# JPA EclipseLink

Tags: java, mysql

i am using Java Eclipse oxygen and Mysql for Database. I am trying to Persist data on my sql. It says "*Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.*"  how can it be solved? Thank you.

```
<properties> 
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> 
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdata"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/> 
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/> 
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/> 
</properties>
```

Comment: how does your datasource configuration look like?

Comment: <properties> 
 
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>  

<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdata"/> 
 
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>  
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>  

<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/> 
 
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/> 
 
</properties>

Comment: and which mysql jdbc driver are you using?

Comment: Driver name "mysql-connector-java-5.1.4"

Comment: try to remove <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
```

The ServiceLoader mechanisme will find the driver by its own.

Comment: I press active and vote. I don't know how to add the answer since i am new for this. Thank you.